# C# Array not utilizing inputs

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, integer, user-input

I am new to programming and am taking a class. Our assignment is to allow specific integer inputs and then return said integer inputs in numerical order. I have everything working all the way up to where you put in the integers. However, whenever it replicated through unsorted and sorted Arrays, all the numbers come back as zeros. I've been working on this thing for 13 hours straight now and haven't been able to figure it out. I think I'm missing some sort of simple understanding with the Arrays and how they interact with the user inputs. I'm super-excited to have started programming recently, but I've been running into a lot of walls.

Many thanks to anyone who can help clarify anything.

```
namespace HighScoreTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            bool valid = false;
            int HSTable = 0;
            while (!valid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine
                    ("How many high scores do you want?");
                if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out HSTable) && HSTable > 0)
                
                {
                    valid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid Input. ");                  
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nYou want  " + HSTable + "  highscores.");

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your highscores:");
            Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 1; i < HSTable; i++)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                /* This should creates a string the size of HSTable, which was the answer to, "How hany highscores do you want?" */
            }

           
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("High Scores - Unsorted");       
            
            int[] highscores = new int[HSTable];

            PrintArray(highscores);
            SortArrayHighToLow(highscores);
                        
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("High Scores - Sorted");


            
            PrintArray(highscores);

            
            Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit . . .");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }    
        public static void PrintArray(int[] highscores )
        {
           
            for (int i = 0; i < highscores.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(highscores[i]);              
            }
        }

        
        static void SortArrayHighToLow(int[] numbers)
        {
            int tmp;
            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j > 0 && numbers[j] > numbers[j-1]; j--)
                {
                    tmp = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
                    numbers[j - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've rewatched all our available lectures and resources and have even gone online to try and see what will work, but I can't seem to get a grasp of what exactly I need. I feel that some 1 on 1 with a more experienced programmer could shine some light on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are initalizing array, but not actually passing any value to them

```
int[] highscores = new int[HSTable];
```

This line initializes a new array with size of HSTable, however you need to set values to nembers of your array. You could use your own code for example:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < HSTable; i++)
        {
            //you should use TryParse here as this can result in exceptions
            highscores[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
```

Also since arrays start from index 0 and not 1, I strongly recommend that you start iterating from 0.

I hope I got your problem clear, happy coding!

Comment: This helped me understand a little! But now I've run into "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format." whenever I tried to utilize the line of code you suggested and TryParse receives an error that says, "No Overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments' The Main is a string, but I am trying to use an array of integers. Could that be a reason why some things aren't resulting as intended? I've just started programming for about a week now and am still trying to find out all the basics.

Comment: Try Parse actually tries to parse to integer and sets into default value if it were not able to convert it to int. So if you want to use try parse, you should read following:


https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0

for ex:
         int number;

         bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine` reads a line of input and returns it. You have to actually use that input but you're just ignoring it. Also, if you're asking the user to input the number of values to expect, why would you be reading it in a loop? There's just going to be one value in that case, then you will need to loop that number of times:

```cs
HSTable = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then you create the array with that many elements, then you loop to read that many inputs.

Comment: If you are referring to loop at the beginning of the code, it repeats until the user inputs an integer. If a char, string, 0 or negative number is entered, it will prompt for a different answer. Is there a better way to implement that? /could the way I implemented it be interfering with the rest of the code? The start of the process worked this way until after receiving the user inputs and returning the "Sorted" result as all 0's.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this forum, too. A coding student as you.

Some thoughts for your first part:

- would it be helpful to have an exit strategy for your loop?
- would it be more easy to split up your code in the first if-statement?
- would it be helpful to the user to receive more information of what input is accepted?

Just some ideas, I tried to implement in my code here below; maybe it is of some use for you.

```c
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace CodingSolutions
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "CodingSolutions";

            bool invalidValue = true;
            int inputValue;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of highscore elements. The value must be a natural number. Enter <0> to leave.");
            
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
                    inputValue = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An Exception was thrown. You need to enter a natural number. N = { 0, 1, 2, 3, ...}");
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + e.Message);
                    continue;
                }

                if (inputValue == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are leaving the program");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    invalidValue = false;
                }
                else if (inputValue < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a natural number. N = { 0, 1, 2, 3, ...}");
                }
                else if (inputValue > 0)
                {
                    FillHighscoreTable(inputValue);
                    invalidValue = false;
                }

            } while (invalidValue);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            Console.WriteLine("***** End Of Program <{0}> *****", Console.Title);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void FillHighscoreTable(int highscoreTableLength)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Code to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```